# Why is the $E(\sum x_i) = \sum x_i$ isn't it a non-determinestic value? Also how do I find the variance for this?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> We have $Y = \beta x + e$ with ($e\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$)
>   . We also have the estimate of $\beta$ which is $\hat{\beta} = \dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$. Consider $\hat{\beta}$ as if = $\beta$ for this problem.

I have trouble understanding how the $var(\beta) = \dfrac{(\sum x_i)^2}{\sum x_i^2} n\sigma^2$ by using the information below:

$E(y_i) = E(\beta x_i + e_i) = \beta x_i$

$Var(y_i) = \sigma^2$ <== Can someone explain me why is it the case?

This is the method used to find the $E(\beta) = \dfrac{1}{\sum x_i^2} \sum x_i E(y_i) = ... = \beta$. <== This seems to imply that the E($\sum x_i$) = $\sum x_i$. However don't we have a non-determinestic value here?

As for the variance can someone please demonstrate the above result?

Comment: $x_i$ are actual observations. They are deterministic. The only random variables here are $Y$ and $e$, and $Y$ is random only because of $e$, not because of $x$ or $\beta$.

Comment: why is x not a random variable?

Comment: In the standard "simple linear regression model" it is that way: the $x_i$ are known constants, $\beta$ is an unknown constant, the errors $e_i$ are independent random with expectation $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and the data we observe are the $y_i=\beta x_i + e_i$.  These are the ground rules for the game you are apparently playing.

Comment: ah ok thank you it explains a lot does it work is it the same way for the variance?

Answer (score 1):

A random variable is something that, if measured repeatedly, might change from observation to observation. Note that $x$ does not have that property; only $e$ does. (I endorse kimchi lover's explanation in the comments.)

As for the variance: because $\beta, x$ are constants, it follows that $\operatorname{Var}(\beta x + \epsilon) = \operatorname{Var}(\epsilon) = \sigma^2.$

*Proof* of previous claim: If $Z$ is a random variable and $a$ is a constant, then 
\begin{align*}
  \operatorname{Var}(a + Z) &= \mathbb E[(a + Z - \mathbb E[a + Z])^2] \\
 &= \mathbb E[(a + Z - a - \mathbb E[Z])^2] \\
&= \mathbb E[(Z - \mathbb E[Z])^2] \\
&= \operatorname{Var}(Z).
\end{align*}